# Textbooks for Teaching Intro Micro (Principles): What are the tradeoffs?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, teaching

As a new AP, I'm assigned to teach Principles of Microeconomics. Different teaching mentors I've asked about course materials have mentioned different texts, but I'm having a hard time getting a sense of the trade-offs between options. This may be because there are not actually any substantive differences, but I'd love thoughts from anybody who has explored, taught from, or switched between multiple books.

For context I have the most familiarity with Mankiw, but was recommended Stevenson/Wolfers by one of my colleagues. These two have most of my attention since they have micro-only versions, but I'd be open to teaching just the micro chapters from other books.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can't really give you an answer because I am currently teaching AP with on the Barron's Review book, but I can say that having epub versions of your textbook really helps when making presentations. Using epub I can easily copy and paste a lot of useful diagrams straight from the book.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I looked at a number of books and decided on Stevenson and Wolfers (by MacMillan). Big selling points to me were that the book covers a lot of more "modern" topics (like social insurance and redistribution, strategic management, game theory, and behavioral economics), that the text and examples are really interesting (my wife said a book like this might have made her majored in econ after she read through a few sections, and that the publisher give students free access to iClicker software.

Turns out ex-post that the students really like the framing of "core principles" showing up in each of the chapters.